# "Biased" SVM classification results for random data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am currently generating ROC-AUC SVM classification results (using `sklearn`) for random, normally distributed data to use as baseline for my experiment. I have repeated this 100 times, each time generating a new random data-set, and obtaining a mean ROC-AUC score over the CV-test sets. At the end, I got a distribution of 100 mean ROC-AUC scores, which I expected to be centered around 0.5 and fairly symmetric.

However, while the distribution is fairly centered around 0.5 and clearly compatible with chance, it also exhibits a visible tail of high ROC-AUC scores. I understand 100 iterations may be too few, however I have repeated this for multiple experiments/classification tasks with different sample sizes, every time generating new random data, and the same asymmetric results towards high ROC-AUC scores were observed, more or less pronounced depending on the sample-size and randomness.

- Is there something wrong with my code/experiment design that is indeed causing the results to be biased?
- Or this is to be expected and actually not an issue?

Here is a reproducible example. Please let me know if you spot a fundamental flaw in the pipeline. If you want to run it, on my laptop (4 CPU cores) it took about 1h, but this is not necessary: I'd still greatly appreciate  if you could just inspect the code.

A histogram of the rng ROC-AUC scores produced with this is also provided.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

r = 1
# Data-set dimensions and imbalance to match original data.
X, y = make_classification(n_samples = 105, n_features = 24, weights = [27/105], random_state = r)
scores = list()
for rng in range(100):
    X = np.random.normal(size = X.shape)
    clf = Pipeline([('anova', SelectKBest()), ('svc', SVC(kernel = 'linear'))])

    # Reduced grid-search for convenience
    K = [1, 2, 5]   
    C = [0.1, 1]
   
    space = dict()
    space['anova__k'] = K
    space['svc__C'] = C
    
    scores_ = list()
    cv_out = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 10, random_state = r)
    for train_indx, test_indx in cv_out.split(X, y):
        X_train, y_train = X[train_indx, :], y[train_indx]
        X_test, y_test = X[test_indx, :], y[test_indx]        

        cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 5, random_state = r)
        search = GridSearchCV(clf, space, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv = cv, refit = True, n_jobs = -1)
        result = search.fit(X_train, y_train)
        best_model = result.best_estimator_
        
        y_pred = best_model.decision_function(X_test)
    
        scores_.append(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred))
        
    scores.append(scores_)
    print('Rng iteration:', rng + 1, '/ 100')

plt.hist(np.mean(np.array(scores), axis = 1))
plt.xlabel('ROC-AUC')
plt.show()
```

[image]

PS. The classes are imbalanced. Under/over-sampling has been tested in other parts of the experiment, but I believe this is not relevant for this specific problem. In fact, symmetric distributions were instead observed when using random forest, albeit with no internal-CV for model selection (using default parameters).

Comment: I could only guess that you should first try to reproduce the effect in a much simpler setting, without all the grid search and CV (inner & outer) fuss. That would possibly be easier for others to reproduce w/o committing to 1hr long experiments; it also makes much more sense from a *debugging* perspective: start simple and see if the issue is still there; if it is, throw away all the redundant (and probably irrelevant) characteristics.

Comment: I understand that 1h on a similar machine might be too long. However I think the code is conceptually fairly simple for a machine learning application (two CV loops and a grid search), so even if someone can't understandably test the code themselves, I'd still greatly appreciate if they could give it a look. Just in case there's something clearly wrong with my pipeline.